# Why is my iTunes artwork not changed when uploading a new version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

In my supporting files folder there is a file artwork_1024x1024.png so I imagined that this file was uploaded with the binary and handled properly too. Right now when the app is reviewed and ready for sale i only see the old artwork file and can't find an option to change that.

Do I really have to submit a new version just for the large iTunes icon? Or is there another, simpeler way? It feels a bit silly to submit a new version (and bother the customers with a new download while there is no real change in the app).

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will need to submit a new version, Apple no longer allows you to change artwork since it was misused by developers to show Apps function that are not really in the App.

Also the iTunes artwork show in iTunes/App Store can only by uploaded in iTunesConnect. No icons from your app are used in on the App Store.

Comment: OK, thank you very much. Do you know if it is possible to submit the same archive as a new version (was 2.0 and stays 2.0) and only change the artwork file or do I have to make a new binary (2.0.1)?

Comment: No you will need to increase your bundle version. So it is going to be version 2.0.1